# Code not running when trying to display pointer values and pointer addresses

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof, memory-address

I am taking a course in C and just started learning about pointers. I just went to go complete this section's lab and I couldn't get my code to run properly. So I opened up the lab's correct answer code, and then I went through line by line and compared the lab's answer code to my own. Some of my label's are different, but nothing that should be causing any errors.

I can't figure out why my code won't run, but the lab's code will.

Here is a picture of what happens in xcode when I try to run my code:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code that is not working:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{


    int age = 40;
    float gpa = 3.25;
    char grade = 'A';
    double x = 0.000009;
    char companyName[20];

    printf("The address of age is: %d\n", &age);
    printf("The size of age is: %lu\n", sizeof(age));

    printf("The address of gpa is: %d\n", &gpa);
    printf("The size of gpa is: %lu\n", sizeof(gpa));

    printf("The address of grade is: %d\n", &grade);
    printf("The size of grade is: %lu\n", sizeof(grade));

    printf("The address of x is: %d\n", &x);
    printf("The size of x is: %lu\n", sizeof(x));

    printf("The address of companyName is: %d\n", &companyName);
    printf("The size of companyName is: %lu\n", sizeof(companyName));


    int *pointerIntAge;

    pointerIntAge = &age;

    float *pointerFloatGpa;

    pointerFloatGpa = &gpa;

    char *pointerCharGrade;
    pointerCharGrade = &grade;

    double *pointerDoubleX;

    pointerDoubleX = &x;

    char *pointerCharCompanyName;

    pointerCharCompanyName = &companyName;


    printf("The value of pointerIntAge is: %d\n", *pointerIntAge);
    printf("The value of pointerFloatGpa is: %f\n", *pointerFloatGpa);
    printf("The value of pointerCharGrade is: %c\n", *pointerCharGrade);
    printf("The value of pointerDoubleX is: %f\n", *pointerDoubleX);
    printf("The valie of pointerCharCompanyName is: %s\n", *pointerCharCompanyName); 


    printf("The address of pointerIntAge is: %p\n", pointerIntAge);
    printf("The address of pointerFloatGpa is: %p\n", pointerFloatGpa);
    printf("The address of pointerCharGrade is: %p\n", pointerCharGrade);
    printf("The address of pointer DoubleX is: %p\n", pointerDoubleX);
    printf("The address of pointerCharCompanyName is: %p\n", pointerCharCompanyName);

    *pointerIntAge+=5;
    printf("Just added 5 to pointer age\n");
    printf("The new value of age is: %d\n", age);

    printf("The value of age through pointer is: %d\n", *pointerIntAge);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the lab's code that is working:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int age = 40;
    float gpa = 3.25;
    char grade = 'A';
    double x = 0.000009;
    char companyName[20];

    printf("Address of age: %d\n", &age);
    printf("Size of age: %lu\n", sizeof(age));
    printf("Address of GPA: %d\n", &gpa);
    printf("Size of age: %lu\n", sizeof(gpa));
    printf("Address of grade: %d\n", &grade);
    printf("Size of grade: %lu\n", sizeof(grade));
    printf("Address of x: %d\n", &x);
    printf("Size of x: %lu\n", sizeof(x));
    printf("Address of companyName: %d\n", &companyName);
    printf("Size of companyName: %lu\n", sizeof(companyName));

    int *pAge;
    pAge = &age;
    float *pGpa;
    pGpa = &gpa;
    char *pGrade;
    pGrade = &grade;
    double *pX;
    pX = &x;
    char *pCompanyName;
    pCompanyName = &companyName;

    printf("\nValue of Age though pointer: %d", *pAge);
    printf("\nValue of GPA though pointer: %0.2f", *pGpa);
    printf("\nValue of Grade though pointer: %c", *pGrade);
    printf("\nValue of X though pointer: %f", *pX);
    printf("\nValue of Company Name though pointer: %s\n", *pCompanyName);

    printf("\nThe address from Age pointer: %p", pAge);
    printf("\nThe address from Gpa pointer: %p", pGpa);
    printf("\nThe address from Grade pointer: %p", pGrade);
    printf("\nThe address from X pointer: %p", pX);
    printf("\nThe address from companyName pointer: %p\n", pCompanyName);

    *pAge += 5; //Added 5 to Age through pointer.
    printf("\nValue of Age: %d", age);
    printf("\nValue of Age through pointer: %d", *pAge);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? What's your actual output from *your* code (not the lab's)?

Comment: @Jonah I just updated my original post with a screenshot of what I'm getting in xcode when trying to run.

Answer (score 1):

`companyName` is not initialised so `printf("The valie of pointerCharCompanyName is: %s\n", *pointerCharCompanyName);` will either print garbage (if there is a NULL somewhere in it) or run out of bounds (if there isn't).

This is because strings (really just character arrays) in C are expected to be null-terminated. That means they should have a '\0' character at the end - this is used by methods operating on the string to know where the string ends.

Try `char companyName[20] = { 0 };` or `char companyName[20] = { "some string" };`

There are some other things to fix, though.

1. Use `%p` to print addresses, not `%d`.
2. If you had compiler warnings on you would have noticed that `pointerCharCompanyName = &companyName;` and `printf("The valie of pointerCharCompanyName is: %s\n", *pointerCharCompanyName);` both have issues caused by poor understanding of pointers.
3. If the example code that supposedly works really is example code, it exhibits these problems too and you should find a new class.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line: `pCompanyName = &companyName;`

You need to turn compiler warnings on. You should have gotton a warning "assignment from incompatiable pointer type."

companyName is already a pointer. So your line tries to assign a pointer to the address of a pointer (i.e. a pointer to a pointer).

It should be: `pCompanyName = &companyName[0];` or simply `pCompanyName = companyName;`

Also you are using %d instead of %p in lines like `printf("The address of age is: %d\n", &age);`

Also both versions of the code incorrectly use %lu instead of %u for sizeof (which returns size_t which is unsigned int, not unsigned long).

The lab code is also wrong. If or not it crashes is dumb luck based on how the memory is allocated. You also have the problem of using %s to print a string that has not value, and therefore will randomly may or may not have a null terminator. You need to also put characters with null terminator into company name. Something like `companyName[20] = "test";`

Comment: Thank you for the input, but you are making corrections to the 2nd code I posted which actually runs just fine. My problem is that I can't get my set of code, the first code I posted, to run.

Comment: There's nothing that will cause his error from doing `pCompanyName = &companyName;`. Please see my answer for the likely cause of your memory access error. If the lab's code really is exactly as you have typed it then it contains the same problem as yours, it just might not always cause a crash.

Comment: @Eric `%s\n", *pCompanyName);` No wonder, they are teaching them to print garbage.

Comment: Are you guys saying that the instructor did a shitty job with this code?

Comment: @user3055015 Definitely, if it was really provided as you have shown us _and_ was not specifically intended to teach you about these problems.